# Xamarin AlarmManager not firing when app sleeps

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, alarmmanager

I have following code to fire an alarm at exact time. **When my app goes to sleep/background, Alarm does not FIRE**, however as soon as I unlock my phone, then it fires right away.

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(MyReceiver));
    i.PutExtra("Speaker", txtSpeaker.Text);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);

    string _date = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")  ;
    string _time = tpick.Hour + ":" + tpick.Minute;
    DateTime scheduleAt = Convert.ToDateTime(_date).Add(TimeSpan.Parse(_time));
    DateTimeOffset dateOffsetValue = DateTimeOffset.Parse(scheduleAt.ToString());
    var millisec = dateOffsetValue.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(AlarmService);
    alarmManager.SetExact(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, millisec, pi);
```

and here is my Receiver Class...

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class MyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public async override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {


        Console.WriteLine("FIRED");

        String result = intent.Extras.GetString("Speaker");

        Toast.MakeText(context, "Alarm Ringing!", ToastLength.Short).Show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the App is running on API 23 or newer, you might want to look into using the [`SetExactAndAllowWhileIdle` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)). According to the documentation it appears to me that this method will ignore whether the Device is in some low-power state or doze is enabled.